# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'grid'

Tags: python, tkinter

Im a streamer and new to python if anyone can helpo me sort this out ill be super greatful!

```
import tkinter as tk import random


window = tk.Tk()

window.title("Randomizer")

window.geometry("400x400")


#----RANDOM SELECT GEN--------
def random_gen():
    Champ=['Aatrox',    'Ahri',     'Akali',    'Alistar',  'Amumu',    'Anivia',   'Annie',    'Ashe',     'Azir',     'Blitzcrank',   'Brand',    'Braum',    'Caitlyn',  'Cassiopeia',   'ChoGath',  'Corki',    'Darius',   'Diana',    'Dr. Mundo',    'Draven',   'Elise',    'Evelynn',  'Ezreal',   'Fiddlesticks',     'Fiora',    'Fizz',     'Galio',    'Gangplank',    'Garen',    'Gnar',     'Gragas',   'Graves',   'Hecarim',  'Heimerdinger',     'Irelia',   'Janna',    'Jarvan IV',    'Jax',  'Jayce',    'Jinx',     'Kalista',  'Karma',    'Karthus',  'Kassadin',     'Katarina',     'Kayle',    'Kennen',   'KhaZix',   'KogMaw',   'LeBlanc',  'Lee Sin',  'Leona',    'Lissandra',    'Lucian',   'Lulu',     'Lux',  'Malphite',     'Malzahar',     'Maokai',   'Master Yi',    'Miss Fortune',     'Mordekaiser',  'Morgana',  'Nami',     'Nasus',    'Nautilus',     'Nidalee',  'Nocturn',  'Nunu',     'Olaf',     'Orianna',  'Pantheon',     'Poppy',    'Quinn',    'Rammus',   'RekSai',   'Renekton',     'Rengar',   'Riven',    'Rumble',   'Ryze',     'Sejuani',  'Shaco',    'Shen',     'Shyvana',  'Singed',   'Sion',     'Sivir',    'Skarner',  'Sona',     'Soraka',   'Swain',    'Syndra',   'Talon',    'Taric',    'Teemo',    'Thresh',   'Tristana',     'Trundle',  'Tryndamere',   'Twisted Fate',     'Twitch',   'Udyr',     'Urgot',    'Varus',    'Vayne',    'Veigar',   'VelKoz',   'Vi',   'Viktor',   'Vladimir',     'Volibear',     'Warwick',  'Wukong',   'Xerath',   'Xin Zhao',     'Yasuo',    'Yorick',   'Zac',  'Zed',  'Ziggs',    'Zilean',   'Zyra',     'aphelios',     'aurelion sol',     'bard',     'Camille',  'ekko',     'illaoi',   'ivern',    'kaisa',    'jhin',     'kayne',    'kindred',  'kled',     'lillia',   'neeko',        'ornn',     'pyke',     'qiyana',   'rakan',    'xayah',    'sett',     'senna',    'Sylas',    'tahm kench',   'Taliyah',  'yone',     'yuumi',    'zoe']  
    Lane=['top','bottom','middle','support','jungle']
    Build=['AD','Tank','AP','Crit','Attack speed','Assassin']

    x=random.choice(Build)
    y=random.choice(Champ)
    z=random.choice(Lane)

    print (x),(y),(z)


#------ANSWER PULL-------------
def random_display():
    result = random_gen()
    results_display = tk.Text(master=window, height=10, width=30)
    random_display.grid(column=0, row=3)

    results_display.insert(tk.END, result)

#-----BUTTON---------------

button = tk.Button(text="Goodluck!", command=random_display)
button.grid(column=0, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Blockquotes muddle up your code and make it unintelligible. See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/628368)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your corrected code:

```
import tkinter as tk 
import random


window = tk.Tk()

window.title("Randomizer")

window.geometry("400x400")


#----RANDOM SELECT GEN--------
def random_gen():
    Champ = ['Aatrox', 'Ahri', 'Akali', 'Alistar', 'Amumu', 'Anivia', 'Annie', 'Ashe', 'Azir', 'Blitzcrank', 'Brand', 'Braum', 'Caitlyn', 'Cassiopeia', 'ChoGath', 'Corki', 'Darius', 'Diana', 'Dr. Mundo', 'Draven', 'Elise', 'Evelynn', 'Ezreal', 'Fiddlesticks', 'Fiora', 'Fizz', 'Galio', 'Gangplank', 'Garen', 'Gnar', 'Gragas', 'Graves', 'Hecarim', 'Heimerdinger', 'Irelia', 'Janna', 'Jarvan IV', 'Jax', 'Jayce', 'Jinx', 'Kalista', 'Karma', 'Karthus', 'Kassadin', 'Katarina', 'Kayle', 'Kennen', 'KhaZix', 'KogMaw', 'LeBlanc', 'Lee Sin', 'Leona', 'Lissandra', 'Lucian', 'Lulu', 'Lux', 'Malphite', 'Malzahar', 'Maokai', 'Master Yi', 'Miss Fortune', 'Mordekaiser', 'Morgana', 'Nami', 'Nasus', 'Nautilus', 'Nidalee', 'Nocturn', 'Nunu', 'Olaf', 'Orianna', 'Pantheon', 'Poppy', 'Quinn', 'Rammus', 'RekSai', 'Renekton', 'Rengar', 'Riven', 'Rumble', 'Ryze', 'Sejuani', 'Shaco', 'Shen', 'Shyvana', 'Singed', 'Sion', 'Sivir', 'Skarner', 'Sona', 'Soraka', 'Swain', 'Syndra', 'Talon', 'Taric', 'Teemo', 'Thresh', 'Tristana', 'Trundle', 'Tryndamere', 'Twisted Fate', 'Twitch', 'Udyr', 'Urgot', 'Varus', 'Vayne', 'Veigar', 'VelKoz', 'Vi', 'Viktor', 'Vladimir', 'Volibear', 'Warwick', 'Wukong', 'Xerath', 'Xin Zhao', 'Yasuo', 'Yorick', 'Zac', 'Zed', 'Ziggs', 'Zilean', 'Zyra', 'aphelios', 'aurelion sol', 'bard', 'Camille', 'ekko', 'illaoi', 'ivern', 'kaisa', 'jhin', 'kayne', 'kindred', 'kled', 'lillia', 'neeko', 'ornn', 'pyke', 'qiyana', 'rakan', 'xayah', 'sett', 'senna', 'Sylas', 'tahm kench', 'Taliyah', 'yone', 'yuumi', 'zoe']
    Lane = ['top', 'bottom', 'middle', 'support', 'jungle']
    Build = ['AD', 'Tank', 'AP', 'Crit', 'Attack speed', 'Assassin']

    x = random.choice(Build)
    y = random.choice(Champ)
    z = random.choice(Lane)

    return (x, y, z)


#------ANSWER PULL-------------
def random_display():
    result = random_gen()
    results_display = tk.Text(master=window, height=10, width=30)
    results_display.grid(column=0, row=3)

    results_display.insert(tk.END, result)

#-----BUTTON---------------


button = tk.Button(text="Goodluck!", command=random_display)
button.grid(column=0, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

It was not working because of the `print (x), (y), (z)` which should be a `return` instead of print in the random_gen() function

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong variable:

```
results_display = tk.Text(master=window, height=10, width=30)
random_display.grid(column=0, row=3) # <- here
```

should be

```
results_display = tk.Text(master=window, height=10, width=30)
results_display.grid(column=0, row=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you don't mind running the program every time you want a new pick (so at the beginning of each game), you can use this simplified program:

```
from random import randint

CHAMPIONS = ['Aatrox', 'Ahri', 'Akali', 'Alistar', 'Amumu', 'Anivia', 'Annie', 'Ashe', 'Azir', 'Blitzcrank', 'Brand', 'Braum', 'Caitlyn', 'Cassiopeia', 'ChoGath', 'Corki', 'Darius', 'Diana', 'Dr. Mundo', 'Draven', 'Elise', 'Evelynn', 'Ezreal', 'Fiddlesticks', 'Fiora', 'Fizz', 'Galio', 'Gangplank', 'Garen', 'Gnar', 'Gragas', 'Graves', 'Hecarim', 'Heimerdinger', 'Irelia', 'Janna', 'Jarvan IV', 'Jax', 'Jayce', 'Jinx', 'Kalista', 'Karma', 'Karthus', 'Kassadin', 'Katarina', 'Kayle', 'Kennen', 'KhaZix', 'KogMaw', 'LeBlanc', 'Lee Sin', 'Leona', 'Lissandra', 'Lucian', 'Lulu', 'Lux', 'Malphite', 'Malzahar', 'Maokai', 'Master Yi', 'Miss Fortune', 'Mordekaiser', 'Morgana', 'Nami', 'Nasus', 'Nautilus', 'Nidalee', 'Nocturn', 'Nunu', 'Olaf', 'Orianna', 'Pantheon', 'Poppy', 'Quinn', 'Rammus', 'RekSai', 'Renekton', 'Rengar', 'Riven', 'Rumble', 'Ryze', 'Sejuani', 'Shaco', 'Shen', 'Shyvana', 'Singed', 'Sion', 'Sivir', 'Skarner', 'Sona', 'Soraka', 'Swain', 'Syndra', 'Talon', 'Taric', 'Teemo', 'Thresh', 'Tristana', 'Trundle', 'Tryndamere', 'Twisted Fate', 'Twitch', 'Udyr', 'Urgot', 'Varus', 'Vayne', 'Veigar', 'VelKoz', 'Vi', 'Viktor', 'Vladimir', 'Volibear', 'Warwick', 'Wukong', 'Xerath', 'Xin Zhao', 'Yasuo', 'Yorick', 'Zac', 'Zed', 'Ziggs', 'Zilean', 'Zyra', 'aphelios', 'aurelion sol', 'bard', 'Camille', 'ekko', 'illaoi', 'ivern', 'kaisa', 'jhin', 'kayne', 'kindred', 'kled', 'lillia', 'neeko', 'ornn', 'pyke', 'qiyana', 'rakan', 'xayah', 'sett', 'senna', 'Sylas', 'tahm kench', 'Taliyah', 'yone', 'yuumi', 'zoe']
LANES = ['Top', 'Jungle', 'Mid', 'Bottom', 'Support']
BUILDS = ['AD', 'Tank', 'AP', 'Crit', 'Attack speed', 'Lethality']

print(
    CHAMPIONS[randint(0, len(CHAMPIONS))],
    LANES[randint(0, len(LANES))],
    BUILDS[randint(0, len(BUILDS))]
)

input('Press "enter" to close this window...')
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this! Does the rest look like it will execute ok? I'm not at my PC right now to try and run it.

Comment: I tried this code, it works fine, it's just not as pretty as you could expect it to be.